# How do you call url from localStorage

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I want to save a url to localStorage- on a settings page. Then I need a hyperlink or a button that when clicked, goes to that url. Trying not to use jquery.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Local Storage URL</title>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
function save() {
    var myURL = document.getElementById('url');
    localStorage.setItem('url', myURL.value);
}

function load() {
    var storedValue = localStorage.getItem('url');
    if(storedValue) {
        document.getElementById('url').value = storedValue;
    }
}

</script>

</head>

<body onLoad="load()">
<input type="text" id="url" />
<input type="button" value="save" onclick="save()" />
<p>
<-- Here is where I am stuck below --><br>
<a href="('myUrl')">Link to localStorage Address</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @Seki: Looks like he tried using `localStorage` (and the correct API calls, mind you) but came up with an error.

Comment: @ElliotBonneville: It's the nth SO question I am reading today where the is just a bunch of code and what seems to be an assignment without mention of the attempt and/or a related error. Maybe I need some rest, but I still cannot see the specific question outside of the classic "I need code... some ideas?"

Comment: My fault, I have seen the "question" lost in a html comment. Quite not visible at the first sight.

Comment: Sorry for the hastle, should have been more descriptive, the localStorage works fine saving and loading. I, being a new student, am having trouble linking to that data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should set href and innerHTML of anchor tag,

```
<a id="link" href="('myUrl')">Link to localStorage Address</a>

function load() {
    var storedValue = localStorage.getItem('url');
    var linkTag = document.getElementById('link');
    var urlInput = document.getElementById('url');
    if(storedValue) {
        urlInput.value = storedValue;
        linkTag.href = storedValue;
        linkTag.innerHTML = storedValue;
    }
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jNwmm/2/)